# How to post values to a page which is not on the same domain

Tags: asp.net

I have this html code on a webpage:

```
<form action="" type=post>
      <label for="name"><div><br>Account</br></div></label> <input type=text id="name" name="account" size=20 maxlength=32 /><br>
       <label for="name"><div><br>Password</br></div></label> <input type=password id="name" name="password" size=20 maxlength=14 /><br> 
      <button type=submit>Okay</button>
    </form>
```

How can I send from my asp.net webproject values on the other page in the "Account" and "Password" labels?

### The page which contains the labels is not on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an absolute URL in the `action` attribute, like so:

```
<form action="https://othersite.com/login.aspx" type=post>
  <label for="name"><div><br>Account</br></div></label> <input type=text id="name" name="account" size=20 maxlength=32 /><br>
   <label for="name"><div><br>Password</br></div></label> <input type=password id="name" name="password" size=20 maxlength=14 /><br> 
  <button type=submit>Okay</button>
</form>
```

Does this not work for you?